# Reading String from Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to read a string from the paragraph which has format of "abc.xyz" format. I am very new for regular expression and i am stucked hear to read the format, please can any one help me out to get the data
example:

Calendar_year_lookup.Yr,Outlet_Lookup.Shop_name,Article_lookup.Category, Article_lookup.Sale_price, sum(Shop_facts.Quantity_sold)

Output:

```
 Calendar_year_lookup.Yr    
  Outlet_Lookup.Shop_name  
 Outlet_Lookup.Shop_name
Article_lookup.Sale_price
Shop_facts.Quantity_sold
```

code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String  data="Calendar_year_lookup.Yr,Outlet_Lookup.Shop_name,Article_lookup.Category, Article_lookup.Sale_price, sum(Shop_facts.Quantity_sold)";

        //data.matches("\w\.\w");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+[.]\\p{L}+");
        Matcher matchers=pattern.matcher(data);
        //System.out.println(matchers);
        if(matchers.find())
        {
        System.out.println(matchers.group(0));
        }

    }
```

Comment: [Got speed ?](http://regex101.com/r/vF1vW1)

Comment: It didnt worked, i tried with all formats

Comment: It should work, with Java you have to use \\ instead of \.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex should be

```
\\w+[.]\\w+
```

`+` is a quantifier which matches preceding character or group **1** to many times

`.` can be escaped as `\\.` or `[.]`

Now your code would be

```
while(m.find())
{
    m.group(0);//your value
}
```

Comment: I am unable to read complete data. its cutting please check the updated code

Comment: @Chinna you should use `\w`..check out the edit..with `\\p{L}` you are only matching alphabets..you can also use `[\\p{L}_]`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your pattern, the regex would be:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"
```

You would have to escape the backslash in java!

Answer (score -2):

The following might work

```
[a-zA-Z].[a-zA-Z]
```